# what is swift error breakpoint? how to use it ? and swift errors are included in all exceptions error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am using xcode 7.1 there is one option in breakpoint navigator.
there is one optin  `swift error breakpoint`.
when i edit this breakpoint there is `one option type i don't know what i have to pass there value for type` and 
**what is use of this swift error breakpoint? ***

Answer (score 3):

Swift error breakpoint will stop at your throw statement.

For example, if you have a method that can throw on error, and you turn on Swift error breakpoint. When error occurs in this method your program will stop at the line that throws the error.